# An example of linear transormation from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ such that it is onto and null space is infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I am looking for some simple functions, that do the job. But I couldn't find that. Is there any trivial function that work for this?

Comment: Perhaps try $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ first.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example. Consider the map $\Phi:\Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \to \Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ given by $\Phi(f)(x) = f(e^x)$.

Comment: How it is surjective. If $f$ is a function we should define $g(x)=f(log x)$, so that $\phi(g)=f$.

Comment: @MadhanKumar $f(\log x)$ is not defined for $x \leq 0$, but that is essentially the idea. If $g(x)$ satisfies $g(x) = f(\log x)$ **for $x > 0$**, it follows that $\phi(g) = f$